# Android studio - Build command failed

Tags: android-studio

Hi there are many questions asked about this issue but couldn't resolve mine. So posted my error, If someone can guide me to specific error. Thanks

My project syncs with gradle files successfully but hen try to Build project it throws this error:

Im using Cocos game engine

```
   Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\maste\Desktop\PERSONAL\WEBSITE\ANDROID\APPS\1.CONNECT\ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android\proj.android\app\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\maste\Desktop\PERSONAL\WEBSITE\ANDROID\APPS\1.CONNECT\ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android\proj.android\app\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/maste/Desktop/PERSONAL/WEBSITE/ANDROID/APPS/1.CONNECT/ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\maste\Desktop\PERSONAL\WEBSITE\ANDROID\APPS\1.CONNECT\ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android\proj.android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang -j2 NDK_DEBUG=1 C:/Users/maste/Desktop/PERSONAL/WEBSITE/ANDROID/APPS/1.CONNECT/ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/libMyGame.so}
[x86] Compile++      : cocos_extension_static <= CCControlSaturationBrightnessPicker.cpp
[x86] Compile++      : cocos_extension_static <= CCPUCollisionAvoidanceAffectorTranslator.cpp
make: *** [C:/Users/maste/Desktop/PERSONAL/WEBSITE/ANDROID/APPS/1.CONNECT/ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/cocos_extension_static/GUI/CCControlExtension/CCControlSaturationBrightnessPicker.o] Error 3
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [C:/Users/maste/Desktop/PERSONAL/WEBSITE/ANDROID/APPS/1.CONNECT/ConnectTheDotsAndPuzzle_Android/proj.android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/cocos_extension_static/Particle3D/PU/CCPUCollisionAvoidanceAffectorTranslator.o] Error 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by moving project to

> C:/droid/connect/proj.android

Could be something to do with permissions.